# Is yWriter for Mac reputable? Is this a safe download?

Tags: creative-writing, software

I was wondering if anyone has used yWriter for Mac and has downloaded it from Softonic. I feel a little iffy about this site(pic attached). I suppose a better question would be: Is it safe to download from Softonic?

[image: yWriter | softonic website]

Comment: Is this on-topic? Consider http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/276/should-this-site-help-with-specific-writing-software-questions

Comment: yWriter seems to be a specific tool for writers, like Screvener. However, it's not about the tool but downloading it, I think it's off-topic, but not related to this meta question.

Comment: This is the link to Simon Haynes explanation for downloading a version of yWriter that will work on Mac and Linux. http://www.spacejock.com/yWriter5_Linux.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the yWriter website (www.spacejock.com) and there's no mention there of a Mac version anywhere. As it's the personal site of the developer I'd be wary of anything that didn't come directly from there.